# Display entire day in calendar

Tags: calendar, microsoft-teams

Is there any way to make the calendar in Microsoft Teams display the entire workday, instead of just showing a rolling ~6 hour window?

I am using the work week view, but from what I can see you don't see the entire day in either of the other two views either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to depend on your screen resolution. On my screen height (1440px) it shows almost 14 hours a day:

[image: teams screenshot]

So a solution would be to increase the resolution of your screen (by getting a bigger screen).

Teams on Windows also supports zoom with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+scroll. It updates *all* the UI elements, so it's not ideal, but it does work in a pinch.

Comment: Thanks. I had a suspicion there weren't any good solutions, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to check.